# how do i delegate this event

Tags: jquery, html, delegates, event-handling

Guys i am just newly trying delegation of events and have implemented over some part of my code but this is a part where i am facing problem it is not responding in the requirement manner ,maybe because it has another event attached to it.
have a look-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divGrid').on("click", ".edit_tr", function() {
    //$(".edit_tr").click(function()

    var ID=$(this).attr('id');

    $("#client_"+ID).hide();
    $("#staff_"+ID).hide();
    $("#matter_"+ID).hide();
    $("#client_input_"+ID).show();
    $("#staff_input_"+ID).show();
    $("#matter_input_"+ID).show();
  })
  .change(function() {
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    var client=$("#client_input_"+ID).val();
    var staff=$("#staff_input_"+ID).val();
    var matter=$("#matter_input_"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&clientname='+client+'&staff='+staff+'&matter='+matter;

    if(client.length>0 && staff.length>0 && matter.length>0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#client_"+ID).html(client);
          $("#staff_"+ID).html(staff);
          $("#matter_"+ID).html(matter);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      alert('enter something');
    }

  });

  // Edit input box click action
  $(".editbox").mouseup(function() {
    return false;
  });

  // Outside click action
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".text").show();
  });
});
```

and this is the html-

```
<div id="divGrid">
  <table class="footable" data-filter="#filter" id="tableresult" >
    <thead>

      <th>Client name</th>
      <th>Staff name</th>
      <th>Matter</th>
      <th> Delete</th>
    </thead>
    <tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">

      <td class="edit_td" >
        <span id="client_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $clientname; ?></span>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $clientname; ?>" class="editbox" id="client_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /&gt;
               </td>

      <td class="edit_td">
        <span id="staff_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $staff; ?></span> 
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $staff; ?>" class="editbox" id="staff_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
      </td>

      <td class="edit_td">
        <span id="matter_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $matter; ?></span> 
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $matter; ?>" class="editbox" id="matter_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

so how should i do it when i have such a code and i want to retain its property even after reloading.

Comment: Do you even understand the code without indenting?

Comment: What is the __required manner__?

Comment: Your JavaScript has a lot of errors. Will you kindly provide a snippet or http://jsbin.com, so that it is easy for you to replicate and easy for us to update and work?

Comment: @payal_suthar That's awesome. Please make a snippet on http://jsbin.com, make sure it works like how you have it in the local, and let us know the problem, we are happy to solve it for you. Also I have updated your code to look legible.

Comment: @payal_suthar Also, would you like to check this? [**Learning Event Delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: the required manner is that it basically allows me editing in the table row by clicking on it and i want to retain this functionality even after reloading the table . My table gets reloaded every 30 sec . So i learnt that if i will have to retain its functionality even after the reload i should delegate the events but now after doing so . it does not allow me editing even before reloading or after reloading

Comment: @payal_suthar But your (posted) code has syntax error...

Comment: it that correct now?

Comment: @payal_suthar Looks perfect. A snippet would be really good.

Comment: @payal_suthar Any snippet in the process?

Comment: ya doing so..i am new to using this

Comment: @payal_suthar No problem. Sent you a message in Facebook, is that you?

Comment: @payal_suthar You just need to add the HTML Part, along with the JS you are using, then copy and paste the CSS, and JavaScripts along with that. Very simple. `:)` Lemme know if you find any difficulties.

Comment: ya i did that but  how do i save it? @PraveenKumar

Comment: @payal_suthar On the top, there should be an unique URL. Just copy and paste.